# Unable to install Phusion Passenger on Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

Running on a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 18.04 on Virtualbox, Windows 10 as the host OS. Ran the instructions on the Phusion Passenger site [here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/bionic/)

This is the error I'm getting:

```
steve@heartypet-staging:~$ sudo apt-get install -y libnginx-mod-http-passenger
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnginx-mod-http-passenger : Depends: passenger (= 1:5.3.4-1~bionic1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Oddly enough, the exact same instructions work fine on the desktop version.

Comment: Can you explicitly try running `apt-get install passenger`. Also check out this link - https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2076

Comment: It says depends on ruby-rack, and then when I try to install that, it says 'ruby-rack' has no installation candidate

Comment: Today I had the exact same problem, let me know if you find it

Comment: I solved the issue by running commands in the first step here: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/bionic/#step-1:-install-passenger-packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get default source list from here

https://askubuntu.com/a/1036749

Replace  `/etc/apt/source.list` with the file in the link above.
Then `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

And go ahead...

Comment: There is an open issue on the repository better to follow-up here: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2122

Comment: Hello, I followed the above instructions, but when I run 'sudo apt install -y nginx-extras libnginx-mod-http-passenger' I still get the error 'libnginx-mod-http-passenger : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.14.0-0ubuntu1) but 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed' Is there something else I could be missing?

Comment: @chrisallick You will have to uninstall the new version before

Comment: Alright, for anyone who stumbles upon this, you should follow @hamiltonc (on the mentioned git issue). And then you need to also install the libnginx-mod-http-passenger, what happened for me is that it still was not working, but I must have done the wrong order of operations. It is working.

Answer (score 1):

If you having problems with the previous solution, one option is run this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
```

and comment all the lines in this file, then run the command

```
sudo apt-get install passenger
```